# Are questions on beta releses accepted on elementaryos.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

With Loki, like with Freya, I was pleasingly surprised to find the beta better in some respects than the previous version, so I want to use it.

But are questions on the beta release off-topic? And if so, are they all off-topic, or only those related to what normally is expected to be a problem in a beta?

(For example, just asking if in a beta some feature is absent by design or by a possible bug should not be off-topic, in my opinion.)

Answer (score 4):

Technically I believe beta releases to be off-topic. They change too fast to effectively answer, and are not *supposed* to work right. Bugs should be reported on launchpad.

Comment: I think questions on bugs are off-topic anyway, be it stable or beta. - What about questions like: "Will I be able to update from Loki beta to stable?" or other such questions asking for information and not for bug-fixes?

Comment: I'm not sure, it would probably be allowed to exist, but might not get answered very effectively. Things like that are still very changeable.

Answer (score 2):

As we do on Ask Ubuntu, I'd suggest letting Betas and other in-development builds be off topic. It's hard to hit a moving target.